# Can we migrate magento 1.14.1.2 EE to 2.3 CE?

Tags: magento-1.14

Is there any plugin or module to migrate magento from 1.14.2.1 EE to 2.3 CE?
Please share some links or tutorials if you have.

Comment: you can use: `https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/bk-migration-guide.html`  or export data from magento 1, and import to magento 2 with enhanced import extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1)  Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`

2)  Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com                                   
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
```

3)  Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

```
    1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

    2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

    3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
```

4)  Configuring the migration :-

```
    1 Change to the following directory :-
      <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

    2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
      cp config.xml.dist config.xml

    3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

    4 Specify the following at minimum:

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </source>

            <destination>

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </destination>

            <options>

            <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

            </options>
```

5)  Migrate settings :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

6)  Migrate Data :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

7)  Migrate Delta :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```